# Laravel 5.7 - Why does programmatically listing console commands return 0?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm currently trying to return the list of Artisan commands within my Laravel application. I tried running `return var_dump(Artisan::('list'));` with success, but my response was unexpected. It came back as `int(0)` or `0` when I took out the `var_dump()` function. When I run this same command in my console, it returns the list of artisan commands successfully.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Artisan::call()` returns the exit code, just like the command would in the terminal.  An exit code of `0` means the command executed successfully.

`Artisan::output()` can be used to get the last command's output.